# Layer a new label/button/etc. under existing elements? iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4

I'm using storyboards in Xcode 4. I have a view with a bunch of items already on it. I want to add a new label with a solid background under the existing labels, buttons, etc., so that it doesn't cover them up.

How do you do this in storyboards (preferred) or programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for it to draw under the existing views, you just need to insert it in the view hierarchy above the views you want it to draw underneath.

[image]

If you were to insert a view at the level I am pointing at, it will draw on top of the toolbar and the "Program Name" label, but underneath the "Program Icon" label, and everything else below it on the list. You can reorganize this list however you want to get the proper draw ordering by clicking and dragging the views in that list.